# symfony2 migration bundle refuse to migrate

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, stofdoctrineextensions, vichuploaderbundle

Hi guys i have integrate in Page CRUD a slug and image upload with the stofdoctrinebundle and vichuploaderbundle.

Here is the Entity:

```
namespace George\PageBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use George\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * Page
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="George\PageBundle\Entity\PageRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Page
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="text")
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="visible", type="boolean")
 */
private $visible;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="modefied", type="datetime")
 */
private $modefied;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="keywords", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $keywords;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="George\UserBundle\Entity\User",  inversedBy="pages")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $owner;

//@ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
 * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
 */
private $slug;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set visible
 *
 * @param boolean $visible
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setVisible($visible)
{
    $this->visible = $visible;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get visible
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getVisible()
{
    return $this->visible;
}

/**
 * Set created
 *
 * @param \DateTime $created
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setCreated($created)
{
    $this->created = $created;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get created
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getCreated()
{
    return $this->created;
}

/**
 * Set modefied
 *
 * @param \DateTime $modefied
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setModefied($modefied)
{
    $this->modefied = $modefied;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get modefied
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getModefied()
{
    return $this->modefied;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set keywords
 *
 * @param string $keywords
 *
 * @return Page
 */
public function setKeywords($keywords)
{
    $this->keywords = $keywords;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get keywords
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getKeywords()
{
    return $this->keywords;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getOwner()
{
    return $this->owner;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $owner
 */
public function setOwner(User $owner)
{
    $this->owner = $owner;
}

public function getSlug()
{
    return $this->slug;
}

// ..... other fields


/**
 * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
 *
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_image", fileNameProperty="imageName")
 *
 * @var File
 */
private $imageFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @var string
 */
private $imageName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $updatedAt;

/**
 * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
 * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
 * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
 * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
 * during Doctrine hydration.
 *
 * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
 */
public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
{
    $this->imageFile = $image;

    if ($image) {
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
    }
}

/**
 * @return File
 */
public function getImageFile()
{
    return $this->imageFile;
}

/**
 * @param string $imageName
 */
public function setImageName($imageName)
{
    $this->imageName = $imageName;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getImageName()
{
    return $this->imageName;
}
}
```

When i try to migrate with doctrine migrationbundle it trow error "Syntax error or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key name ..."

In the database i have already this unique index:

[image]

I cannot understand why the migration want to add it at is already there.

Comment: First: Are your entities correctly mapped? `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate`

Comment: You can always edit the migration file and delete the creation of the index

Comment: @scoolnico yes the are correctly mapped.

Comment: And what about this command: `php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff` ?

Comment: ahhh i have found that i have used it many times this command so it was generated too munch migrations with the same stuff.... I have commented out what it has duplicate and it works.... I have try this nine time and every time it has build migration... Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create migrations keep in mind that when you generate two or more migrations you will migrate trough the two of them and when one of the migration's change is duplicate you need to remove it from the migration to move forward.